Bootstrap confidence and p-values
Conducting bootstrap to obtain confidence interval is pretty standard (e.g., coefficient in regression and adjust for adjusting for selection).
Since we obtain a confidence interval, we can also use it for hypothesis testing, i.e., ask whether the confidence interval contains 0. But how can we obtain a p-value? I usually see references to permutation testing, but they usually only work under the global-null.
Is there a standard approach to obtain p-values from bootstrap confidence intervals?
